# Generate random numbers using inversion method

Tags: probability

Assume you have an uniformly distributed r.v. $U(0,1)$. Use the inversion method to generate random numbers from an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

I have no idea where to start, can someone please explain the inversion method and help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You 'invert' the cumulative probability of the uniform distribution to the exponential distribution by mapping $p$ in $U(0,1)$ to the $x$ that has the same cumulative distribution.

I found a nice document that explains it in more detail: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4404-Sigman/4404-Notes-ITM.pdf

Example 1.1.1 is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! There is something I didn't understand though, why is it possible to change 1-U(0,1) with just U(0,1)?

Comment: The probability distribution for $U$ is the same as for $1-U$ I think.

Comment: Yeah, why is that?

Comment: If you generate 3 random numbers from U: 0.4, 0.7, 0.1 and subtract them from 1: 0.6, 0.3, 0.9 you still end up with uniformly random numbers, hence the distribution is the same.